# How does runLoop in GCD block work without source

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

I was trying to understand multithreaded programming in iOS.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
               , ^{
                    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
                    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

                    if (connection == nil) {
                        NSLog(@"Request failed");

                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Request sent");
                    }
                    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];//How does this work?
                   });
```

This code works fine and I get callbacks as expected.

In the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRunLoop/run

It is mentioned that 'run' method, 'Puts the receiver into a permanent loop, during which time it processes data from all attached input sources.'

Now, in above code, I didn't attach any source to the runLoop. How does it work?

Comment: Why do you need to perform [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]?

Comment: To get NSURLConnectionDelegate callbacks. Without this, callbacks will not be called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every `NSThread` for properly working needs to be attached to runloop. When you call `dispatch_async()` GCD creates the thread with runloop which you would use with `[NSRunLoop curentRunLoop]`. When you create some work with `NSURLConnection`, as I understand, the created connection is attached to the current runloop as the source. So if you want that runloop would be alive and not to fall asleep, you need to perform `[[NSRunLoop curentRunLoop] run]`. In this case, runloop will get the message when the connection receives it.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

By Apple documentation:

**performSelector can be input source**

> Cocoa defines a custom input source that allows you to perform a
> selector on any thread.

**that's why you need to perfom keep runloop alive:**

> When performing a selector on another thread, the target thread must
> have an active run loop

Comment: Thanks. On further looking for answers, I found that every thread is created with a run loop and as per docs, in NSURLConnection, it schedules the connection on current runLoop.

Comment: @optimus I don't get it. I don't think this answered your question. What is the input source any way?

Comment: As per documentation in NSURLConnection.h, "An NSURLConnections created with the
        +connectionWithRequest:delegate: or -initWithRequest:delegate:
        methods are scheduled on the current runloop immediately, and
        it is not necessary to send the -start message to begin the
        resource load.<p>
". This means, NSURLConnection is attaching an input source to the runloop. How exactly it is doing it (performSelector, custom Input source or something else) is some implementation detail that I didn't expect in the answer.